# qfit in Stata versus qplot (or geom_smooth?) in R

Tags: plot, ggplot2, stata

I want to plot the relationship between two variables. I have approximately 15000 observations so point plots are no option. I originally started plotting the relationship in Stata which gave the results I expected. I decided to switch to R and realized that I do not manage to obtain the same results.

As a result, I am wondering: what is the difference between the code in Stata and R? And how do a duplicate the graph from Stata in R?

In Stata I tried

```
twoway qfit prob1 ps1
```

In R I tried

```
qplot(ps1,prob1, geom='smooth', xlab="temperature", ylab="probability to irrigate", span =0.5)
```

To compare: the graph left is the one in Stata, the graph right is the one in R.
[image]

I also tried combinations with geom_smooth such as:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Mydata_full, aes(ps1,prob1))  + geom_smooth()
```

Which gave again very different results. I guess I am not properly understanding all the difference between these functions. Any hints?

Comment: Scales are different, just look at stats y-axis

Comment: Completely different criteria. R people can glance at https://www.stata.com/help.cgi?twoway_qfit which confirms that `twoway qfit` in Stata is fitting a quadratic, hence "q" means quadratic. I am no authority on R but my understanding is that "q" in `qplot`  means quick and that `qplot` is not at all geared to quadratics but much wider in scope. More importantly, it's evident here that your R syntax is not fitting a quadratic at all, but a smoother, quite likely lo(w)ess or lo(w)ess-like.

Comment: Just a case of please read the documentation.

Comment: Title is wrong as it is `qfit` (Stata) and `qplot` (R).

Comment: Why one curve goes down to the right and the other goes up is also a puzzle, but without a reproducible example only wild speculation is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the good solution is often related to using the correct search terms. I indicated in the question above that I did not know exactly the difference between the graphs, showing that I didn't know where to look. This had nothing to do with not reading the documentation. Nick pointed out that I had to look for quadratic functions, which helped me in scoping my search area. This is the solution:

```
ggplot(Mydata_full,aes(x=ps1)) +
  stat_smooth(aes(y = prob1),method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), size = 1)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))
```

Comment: Good that you now understand what to do, but being unclear what `twoway qfit` does in Stata seems hard to explain if you did read the documentation...  More interestingly in terms of your particular data, why did the graphs look completely different? If the smooth plot is trustworthy, then the quadratic isn't, and vice versa.

Comment: The issue is likely to be statistical, so why not post the data and the problem on Cross Validated?